# Error: no such partition. grub rescue> cannot boot

Tags: windows-7

I deleted my linux partition and now im getting the error:

```
error: no such partition.

grub rescue>
```

I put my windows 7 installation disk in the cd drive but I can't boot from it as when it says Press any key to boot from CD or DVD.. and I press a key, nothing happens and the grub rescue error comes up again. How do I fix this and I need to know ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you deleted the partition but didn't use something like gparted so the partition table still thinks it's there.

Is there any other partitions with data on them? If not you could just format the entire drive to solve this problem, if this is not the case attempt to use something like gparted to make sure your partition table is alright or MBR repair to repair any damage.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your boot from CD issue, can you confirm it is a computer issue, not a disc issue. Can you try booting another disc and see if that will boot?

If you can get your Windows 7 disc working, and assuming you already have Windows installed go ahead and try [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html).
The MBR needs to be restored after uninstalling Linux.